# Apps script - get sidebar information

Tags: html, google-apps-script

For some reason I don't get a value from my dropdown in the sidebar to my script as a var. Later on I run different function based on the input.

I followed multiple tutorials, so I don't get it. The log is empty!

**HTML script**

```
<div>
  <h4>Here you can filter the projects</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="projectFilter">Filter</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="projectFilter">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button id ="runButton" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="pushValue()">Run</button>
</div>

<script>

     function pushValue(){
     var keuze = document.getElementById("projectFilter").value;
     };

     google.script.run.pushValue(keuze);


</script>
```

**Script**

```
function projectForm(){

  const htmlForSidebar = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("projectForm");
  const htmlOutput = htmlForSidebar.evaluate();
  htmlOutput.setTitle("CampSolutions");

  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showSidebar(htmlOutput);

}

function pushValue(data){
 var keuze = data;
 Logger.log(keuze);
}
```

**UPDATED script**

```
<script>
     function pushValue(){
     var keuze = document.getElementById("projectFilter").value;
     google.script.run.pushValue(keuze);
     console.log(keuze);
     Logger.log(keuze);
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### You are not calling `google.script.run.pushValue(keuze)` correctly

If you want it to run after the var `keuze` has been defined - include the call inside `function pushValue()` that you call `onClick`

Side note: If you cannot see `Loggr.log`, implement instead `console.log` and retrieve it through `View->Executions`.

Comment: I still don't get it to work. I have updated my HTML script in the post above. if i look in Excecutions i don't see the function pushValue. Only the function that opens te sidebar. It seems that nothing happend when i click the RUN button.

Comment: You updated script should run correctly as soon as you chose a value and click on the `Run` button. Did you implement some `console.log` into `function pushValue(data)`?

Comment: I really don't get it. I did a console and logger in the html file and in the gs file. I even tryed an alert on the gs side. There was no alert. As far as i can tell the function pushValue() isn't starting.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain myself implement the console.log in the apps script function.also, stupid question: did you manually close the sidebar and then run projectForm() again?